# Is there a work around for the broken IE Tab in Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, ietab

My Firefox upgraded itself automatically to version 3.6, and I found that IE tab is broken there.  Apparently IE tab is known to be broken in this version.

Are there any known workarounds such as these?

- a different plugin with the same functionality
- a way to tell FF to behave in some legacy or compatibility mode for certain plugins
- a new version of IE tab

In the meanwhile I'm glad that Chrome's current release supports plugins, and IE tab works there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Corel IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10909)** is:

> An enhanced version of IE Tab which
>   enables you to use the embedded IE
>   engine within tabs of Mozilla Firefox.
>   It supports Adblock Plus in IE, and
>   can sync cookies between IE and
>   Firefox.

It adds nice features compared to the standard "IE Tab" and works great with Firefox 3.6.
Don't forget to uninstall IE Tab before installing Corel IE Tab.

Comment: I've seen some pretty bad reviews of this addon.  Have you used it?

Comment: Yes, for the same reasons as you. No problem for me. Use the latest version from http://coralietab.mozdev.org/installation.html , it changes quickly and the addon page at Mozilla is not updated often with the newer releases.